# Click Button Until Progress Bar is 100%

Tags: autoit

I am using AutoIt to click on Sim (Yes in Portuguese) on all windows that opens on the program with the code below:

```
#requireAdmin
ShellExecute("...\Desktop\test.xrt")

While True
    $win = WinWait("XP-Remote", "Sim")
    ControlClick($win, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
    WinWaitClose($win)
Wend
```

However, I want to stop when the progress bar is on 100%.

#### Autoit Info

Here is the data of the bar:

[image: progress bar]

And the visible text just show this:

[image: visible text]

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Communicating...
Class:  #32770
Position:   623, 338
Size:   429, 135
Style:  0x94C800CC
ExStyle:    0x00010101
Handle: 0x00000000000B08CE

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  msctls_progress32
Instance:   1
ClassnameNN:    msctls_progress321
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:msctls_progress32; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 1012
Text:   
Position:   11, 52
Size:   402, 29
ControlClick Coords:    151, 22
Style:  0x50000000
ExStyle:    0x00000004
Handle: 0x00000000003306DC

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   788, 437
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xFFFFFF

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
Elasped time:
00:14
Reading project files...


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
```

#### Using Timer

I am using a Timer, because i can't figure out how i can do this.

```
#requireAdmin
ShellExecute("...\Desktop\test.xrt")
$Timer = TimerInit ()
Do
    $win = WinWait("XP-Remote", "Sim")
    ControlClick($win, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
    WinWaitClose($win)
until TimerDiff($Timer)>=5000
```

However, using the progress bar is more error proof.

#### How do you check the progress bar or Do Until it is < 100%?

Edit: Tried to use:

- `GUICtrlRead()`
- `$handle = ControlGetHandle ("Communicating...", "", "[CLASS:msctls_progress32; INSTANCE:1]")`

  ```
  $msg = _SendMessage($handle,$PBM_GETPOS,0,0)
  ```

Maybe not correctly...

#### EDIT:

Using this code:

```
ShellExecute("...\Desktop\test.xrt")
 While True
$handle = ControlGetHandle ("Communicating...", "", "[CLASS:msctls_progress32; INSTANCE:1]")
ConsoleWrite("Progress bar handle: " & $handle & @CRLF)

$msg = _SendMessage($handle,$PBM_GETPOS,0,0)
ConsoleWrite("Position: " & $msg & "%" & @CRLF)
WEnd
```

The Result is infinite:

```
Progress bar handle: 0x00000000
Position: 0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_SendMessage($handle,$PBM_GETPOS,0,0)` is correct.

This should work:

```
#include <SendMessage.au3>
#include <ProgressConstants.au3>

$hWnd = WinWait("Communicating...")
$hWnd_Progress = ControlGetHandle($hWnd,"","msctls_progress321")
While _SendMessage($hWnd_Progress,$PBM_GETPOS,0,0) < 100
    $win = WinWait("XP-Remote", "Sim")
    ControlClick($win, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
    WinWaitClose($win)
WEnd
```

Comment: When i `ConsoleWrite("Position: " & _SendMessage($handle,$PBM_GETPOS,0,0) & "%" & @CRLF)` i get only, i did an infinite loop: `Position: 0%`

Comment: Looking at the Control Data, there is no `Name:` parameter, so i set: `$hWnd = ControlGetHandle("","","msctls_progress321")`

Comment: You have to insert the title of the window (like in my example). An empty Window Title in ControlGetHandle will use the active window. Or does the Title change? Does the window exist when you start your script? Or does it come up later? I updated the answer, so the script waits until the window appears.

Comment: The window appears later, after the application is opened. Thanks Max R.